# How to create a button on related list that gets parent Account ID

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, related-list, button

I am trying to create a custom "Log a phone call" button, the button will be displayed on the related list of Activities on an Account Record.

The button will use a Visual Force page as its source so that it can trigger a visual work flow.

The issue is I need to pass the AccountId of the parent Account that the related list is on as a parameter to the flow.

But when I select Visualforce page as the source it will only let me select the Visualforce page if it uses the standard Task controller.

How can I get the Account Id of the record I am on when I click the custom button on the related Activities list?

Comment: Why are you calling a VF page and not just the flow?

Comment: The page is being used just to make an elegant way to close the flow window. However for testing I removed all that and called the flow directly, please see my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VF page could use a `StandardController` for `Activity` and then your VF page's `action` attribute could execute a method which takes the `id` from the record and performs a redirect to the flow URL providing that ID as a parameter.

The VF page needs no markup in it other than the `<apex:page standardController="Task" extension="yourClass" action="yourMethod" >` since no content will be rendered by this page to the end user.

It's just acting as a router to create the URL to the flow and redirect the user.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_url_setvar.htm

---

**The VF page**

```
<apex:page StandardController="Task" extensions="activityRouter" action="{!routeToFlow}" >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

**The controller**

```
public with sharing class activityRouter {

    public activityRouter(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public PageReference routeToFlow() {

        // get the parameters from this page
        Map<String, String> pageParams = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters();
        system.debug(pageParams);

        // create a new URL to the flow and append our params to it    
        return new PageReference('/someflowUrl?title=' + pageParams.get('title') + '&what_id=' + pageParams.get('what_id'));
    }

}
```

---

**Activity "Log a Call" button override**

[image]

---

**Resulting URL after clicking "Log a Call" button on an Account's Activity History related list**
`https://domain.my.salesforce.com/someflowUrl?title=Call&what_id=001G00000229ESC`

Comment: But don't you need to use `StandardSetController` in order to enable a `List Button`?

Comment: Log a Call isn't a list button, it's just a standard button on Activity that can be overridden.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I need to do further testing.

Comment: I think this is on the right track, however now I have the incredibly odd error that I have asked about on this new question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144123/null-values-on-flow-variables